# def count_dominators(items). Finding Dominators in a List. How to make this more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, loops, time

I was given a problem where I need to find the number of dominators in a list. [Here is a description of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12rsa.png) And here is what I came up with: [my solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTBIG.png)

From what I can tell, the code works but when it gets to very large numbers, like the final test, it takes way to long to return anything. I'm pretty sure there's a way to reduce this into a single loop but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Did you try reading the second paragraph of the assignment description? Did you try following the link there, to get a general sense of why the performance problem arises?

Comment: Hint: If you already knew that a certain element was a dominator, could you use that information to help you figure out faster whether certain other elements are dominators? How?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please include your code as text in the posting. This way it would be easier for other preople to help you (nowbody really loves to typewrite code from a screenshots, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a linear solution I hope u can use it.

in this way, the pointer move from end to start and if find a new maximum, the counter(n) plus one.

```py
def count(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return 0
    lst.reverse()

    max_i = lst[0]
    n = 1
    for x in lst:
        if x > max_i:
            max_i = x
            n += 1
    return n
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't think of this, but it seems so simple now that you pointed it out. Thanks a lot!